# Not able to add fields in Related list for a page layout

Tags: visualforce, related-list, fields

I am trying to add fields in a Related Cases Related list for a Pagelayout in Case object. I am not able to add fields like Record Type, Case Description etc [image: Snap shot of the issue here]

What could be the reason. I dont see the fields Available section to add fields.

Also the Second question is to add this related list in visualforce page. Is there a tag to add this. Please let me know.

I am a System administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I am not too sure WHY those field are not available. Looks like this functionality is not available yet according to [this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpknAAC).

2) You can use [`<apex:relatedList>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm) tag to display related list of records on a VF page

Comment: Got the solution for the 1st question. But what will be the related object in the related list for Related Cases. Do you have the solution

Comment: You can find the relationship name if you go on the child object's lookup field to the parent (in setup). It's the "Child Relationship Name" field. For custom objects you will need to append `__r` in your code.

Comment: That is standard related list for a Case Object. We will not have relationship name. So I need the value for List attribute in apex:relatedList

Comment: Well Got it.. It should be 'Cases' 

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer for this question so that it doesn't float around as "unanswered". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, the reason why you are not seeing fields is because of field permissions that was not set as 'read/write' for the profile